# Validate Swagger OpenAPI Specification yaml

Tags: maven, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have a Spring Boot application that contains the **OpenAPI .yaml specification** file in the resources folder and using the **openapi-generator-maven-plugin**, building the project it generates the API interfaces and then can be used as a maven artifact in another project to implement those APIs.

Currently, I am validating the specification file locally using the [Swagger CLI validate](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli) command through the terminal.

Is there a way to validate the specification.yaml file when building the project using another plugin or something like that?

If no, is there any dependency I can use to validate the .yaml file while running the project?

Comment: check here please https://bartko-mat.medium.com/openapi-generator-to-spring-boot-with-custom-java-validations-623381df9215

Comment: I don‘t want to add custom validation or so but to validate the whole yaml file like with the Swagger CLI description in the link that I‘ve provided.